# Unable to open pdf file in new tab

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring, pdf

I have one requirement where in **html page if user click on button then javascript function gets called and in that function ajax call will fetch content of the pdf file from server**.

Please find the rest controller as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = UriMapping.GET_PDF_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody WebServiceResponse getPdfPath(HttpServletRequest req,
  @RequestParam String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) {
WebServiceResponse res = new WebServiceResponse();
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
  if(!CommonUtil.isBlank(fileName)) {
    String filePath = FieldConstant.PDF_PATH + fileName;

    File f = new File(filePath);
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + f.getName() );
    fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(f.length()));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
      os.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    fis.close();
  } else {
    res.setSucess(false);
    res.setReturnMessage("Something Went Wrong While opening file path !");
  }

} catch (Exception e) {
  LOGGER.error(e.toString());
  res.setSucess(false);
  res.setReturnMessage("Something Went Wrong While opening file path !");
}
LOGGER.info("Response" + res.toString());
return res;
```

}

**FieldConstant.PDF_PATH is fixed path at server where all pdf files resides.**

Below is the client side jquery function where in I have used window.open() function to open pdf in new tab.

```
function test(count){
var fileName = pdfGlobal[count].name;
if(fileName != undefined && fileName != "") {
    var param = {
            "fileName" :fileName
    }
    $.ajax({
        url : '../content/getPdfPath',          
        type : 'post',
        dataType : "json",
        data : param,
        error : function(error,jqXHR, exception) {
            errorMessage(exception);
        },
        success : function(data) {              
            if (data) {
                window.open(data,'_blank');
            } else{
                errorMessage(data.returnMessage);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

**I am getting parsing error like below**

[image]

**Now as the error suggest I found the % in first place of the response !**

[image]

Please help me with this.. I know this is not a big issue but I am confused about what goes wrong. Simply not able to find the root cause ...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ajax is expecting a JSON in return, there is no need for you to use ajax, you can just use window.open, sending fileName by get

```
window.open('../content/getPdfPath?fileName='+fileName,'_blank');
```

So you have to change your controller to

```
@RequestMapping(value = UriMapping.GET_PDF_PATH, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```